custom points on chart axis
There is a chart in the form of a straight line parallel to the OX axis.
How to set the point (label) of their intersection on the OY axis and a couple more
of your own points, for example (0, 3) and (0, 17). 'To set' i.e. indicate in the form of ticks on the axis.
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QGraphicsLineItem
from PySide6.QtCharts import QLineSeries, QChart, QChartView, QValueAxis
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt, QPen, QBrush
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QCoreApplication, QPointF
import sys


class ChartWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(700, 500)
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.legend().setVisible(False)
        self.y_axis = QValueAxis()
        self.y_axis.setRange(0, 20)
        self.y_axis.setLabelFormat("%d")
        self.y_axis.setTickType(QValueAxis.TickType.TicksDynamic)
        self.y_axis.setTickInterval(5)
        self.x_axis = QValueAxis()
        self.x_axis.setRange(0, 100)
        self.x_axis.setLabelFormat("%d")
        self.x_axis.setTickType(QValueAxis.TickType.TicksDynamic)
        self.x_axis.setTickInterval(10)
        self.chart.addAxis(self.x_axis, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignBottom)
        self.chart.addAxis(self.y_axis, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        self.series = QLineSeries()
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            self.series.append(i, 12)
        self.series.setPen(QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.red, 2))
        self.chart.addSeries(self.series)
        self.series.attachAxis(self.x_axis)
        self.series.attachAxis(self.y_axis)
        self.lineItem = QGraphicsLineItem(self.chart)
        pen = QPen(Qt.gray)
        pen.setWidth(10)
        chart_view = QChartView(self.chart)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(chart_view)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cw = ChartWindow()
    cw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


